# C# saving longitude and latitude to SQL Database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, latitude-longitude

I have encountered a bizarre issue when saving Longitude and Latitude to my SQL database.

I have an Address Table, and I'm using Entity Framework 5, not code first though.

The Longitude & Latitude fields are set as `Null-able Floats.

Our problem occurs where we try to update the Address Entity with new Longitude and Latitude properties. All other updates to properties of the Address update fine, but the longitude & latitude don't update SQL server side.

We have stepped through the scenario all the way through to the point that the context updates the Entity, and at the point of the update, the entity has the new co-ordinates.

When the update is complete, all other properties have updated apart form the the Long Lat coordinates.

In Entity Framework, the Longitude and Latitude are set as Type Double, which by my reckoning is correct.

Has anyone else encountered any issues like this or has any suggestions to get this working?

Comment: what is datatype in database?must be decimal

Comment: Have you taken a look at the SQL that is being passed to the SQL database to make sure the columns are included in the Update statement?

Comment: thanks Randy, I'll check that